# How to use matrix to translate polygon

Tags: android

I have a custom imageview with a bitmap which i can scale, pan, pinch.

In the ondraw method of the imageview I draw a polygon whose edges and corners are movable.

To pinch/pan the imageview i use the matrix.

How do I use values from the matrix to move the edges and corners of the rectangle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use Canvas.concat(Matrix matrix) before drawing your shape

Comment: first time i draw the polygon i dont have the matrix, the matrix is constructed only when the bitmap is added. will this stil work?

Comment: i think (but i am not sure) that in this case you will have identity Matrix (not scaled, not translated)

Comment: it does work however the rectangle size changes radically when the images are different. how do i make sure the rectanglelways is inside image.

Comment: not quite sure, but if your rectagle size is smaller than image size then it should be inside

Comment: the rectangle zoomin/out on pinch but doesnt pan, any ideas? i really really appreciate your help i have been stuck on this for days!!!